# How can I take values ​from a column in a table and put them into an array? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with the following code(some table):

**expect-next-month.component.html**

```
        <table id="users">
            <tr>
                <th>Number of month</th>
                <th>Total checking electrical units</th>
                <th>Total assembly</th>
                <th>Total soldering</th>
                <th>Total packing</th>
                <th>Total working days in this month</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let sum of totalWorkPerMonth">
                <td>{{sum.number_of_month}}</td>
                <td>{{sum.total_checking_electrical_units}}</td>
                <td>{{sum.total_assembly}}</td>
                <td>{{sum.total_soldering}}</td>
                <td>{{sum.total_packing}}</td>
                <td>{{sum.total_working_days_in_this_month}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The goal is to take all the data from the **total_packing** column and put it into an array in the ts file that I can validate. (This is a column with int values).

Anyone know maybe how to do it? I tried to use ngModel but it did'nt really work... maybe I did'nt write it correctly or it's not possible to get all the values ​​in this way for one variable of an array type.
Would appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** you can get it in a new array in your .ts file using map function

```
var result = this.totalWorkPerMonth.map(x => x.total_packing)

// apply your verification foreach item from your list:
result.foreach(packing => {
  // do something
}
```

**2.** another way is to apply a method to your attribute:

```
<td>{{validateField(sum.total_packing)}}</td>
```

and your `.ts`:

```
 validateField(value: int) {
  // do something
  if (value < 0) return 0;
  else return value;
 }
```

**3.** and third solution, which personally I think is the best: do validation before rendering the result, when you get the data.

Supposing you have a method `getData()` in your component and you want to apply a validation on this field:

```
getData() {
   service.getData().subscribe(data => {
      data.foreach(row => {
         // do your validation as in example
         if (row.total_packing< 0) {
           row.total_packing = 0;
         }
      }
      this.totalWorkPerMonth = data;
   });
}
```

Comment: I wrote in the ts file as you wrote, I tried to do cosole.log to see if the array was indeed filled
But the array is empty


  result = this.totalWorkPerMonth.map(x => x.total_packing);

  checkButton()
  {
    console.log(this.result);
  }

Comment: The `map` in the first method isn't the [RxJS operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map), it's the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. The are called the same, but serve quite different purposes.

Comment: @MichaelD, yep, sorry, here map() is a js method which is applied on each element of an array.